# How to test changing state

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have component as follows in TypeScript:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {App} from "../../../../interfaces/interfaces";
import {map, find, filter} from "lodash";
import NavigationItem from "./NavigationItem";
import {useLocation, useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';

interface NavigationProps {
    applications: App[],
    companyName: string
}

const Navigation: React.FC<NavigationProps> = ({applications, companyName}: NavigationProps) => {
    const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState<boolean>(false)
    const location = useLocation();
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const activeApplication = find(applications, application => application.url === location.pathname);
    const inactiveApplications = filter(applications, application => application.url !== location.pathname)

    return (
        <div data-testid="navigation-component" className="flex h-full">
            <div className="z-[2]">
                <NavigationItem application={activeApplication}
                                companyName={companyName}
                                handleClick={() => setExpanded(expanded => !expanded)}
                                selected={expanded}
                />
            </div>

            <div data-testid="inactive-items" className={`flex transform transition ${expanded ? 'translate-x-0' : '-translate-x-full'}`}>
                {map(inactiveApplications, application => {
                    return <NavigationItem key={application.id}
                                           application={application}
                                           companyName={companyName}
                                           handleClick={() => {
                                               setExpanded(false);
                                               navigate(application.url);
                                           }}
                    />
                })}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Navigation;
```

I want to write test for it.I want to test the `click event`. Thus I should check has it been clicked on active nav item and is the `expanded` state is updated.

The next one is (only if `expanded` state is `true`), check click event on inactive elements and check if that click event updates the expanded state back to false and navigate to another route.

What I have is as follows:

```
    import Header from "./Header";
    import Navigation from "./components/Navigation";
    import {MemoryRouter} from "react-router-dom";
    
    import {describe, it} from "@jest/globals";
    import {act, fireEvent, render, screen, waitFor} from "@testing-library/react";
    import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";
    
    describe("<Navigation />", () => {
    it("checks navigation clicks events", () => {
        const applications = [
            {id: 1, name: "Home", url: "/", classes: "bg-gray-100 text-blue-800"},
            {id: 3, name: "Sales", url: "/sales", classes: "bg-red-500 text-white"},
            {id: 2, name: "Expert", url: "/expert", classes: "bg-green-400 text-white"}
        ];
        const companyName = 'My company';
        render(<MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/"]}>
            <Navigation applications={applications} companyName={companyName} />
        </MemoryRouter>);

        // Get the selected NavigationItem
        const activeNavigationItem = screen.getByTestId(applications[0].name);

        // Simulate click event
        fireEvent.click(activeNavigationItem);
        // Check if click updated the state, changed expanded to true AND maybe check if other inactive NavigationItems have translate-x-0 class


        // Check if expanded is true, if it's true, then check if clicking one of the other NavigationsItems sets it to false and navigate to proper route
    });
});
```

I'm not sure how to get state and check if it has been changed.

Comment: testing library intentionally [abstracts from component's implementation details](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61813319/8389583). You should rather test the behaviour caused by changing the component's state.

Answer (score 0):

@Ibsn is right. RTL wants you to assert the state has changed by looking at elements in the DOM. If you are hiding your elements with CSS, you cannot easily confirm whether the component is actually visible, but you can query the jest-dom by class name.

```
import {render} from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './App';

test('renders react component', () => {
  const {container} = render(<App />);

  // eslint-disable-next-line testing-library/no-container, testing-library/no-node-access
  const boxes = container.getElementsByClassName('box');

  console.log(boxes.length); // ️ 2

  expect(boxes.length).toBe(2);
});
```

[source](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/react-testing-library-find-by-classname)

However, you might have an easier time (if it's possible for you) to show and hide your elements using a boolean. This makes the test much easier.

```
<div data-testid="inactive-items" className={`flex transform transition`}>
  {map(inactiveApplications, (application) => {
    return expanded && ( // if expanded is false, the component will not render
      <NavigationItem
        key={application.id}
        application={application}
        companyName={companyName}
        selected={expanded}
        handleClick={() => {
          setExpanded(false);
          // navigate(application.url);
        }}
      />
    );
  })}
</div>
```

Here's a working [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-babbage-jk6hrw?file=/src/App.tsx:1561-2130)

With this you could amend your test to something like this...

```
const activeNavigationItem = screen.getByTestId(applications[0].name);

expect(activeNavigationItem).not.toBeInTheDocument();
userEvent.click(activeNavigationItem);
expect(activeNavigationItem).toBeInTheDocument();
```

Note, to use `.toBeInTheDocument`, you must also import [@testing-library/jest-dom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@testing-library/jest-dom)

Also, `userEvent` is now recommended over `fireEvent`, from what I've read.

Hope this helps.